# Linux shell script to search for /tmp and append or replace mount options in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have some issues trying to harden RHEL7 using my custom shell script. I would like to add the `nodev` mount option to `/tmp` partition inside `/etc/fstab`.

Is there any command that I can use to search for the occurrence of `/tmp` and then edit the mount options on that line?

The sample of the line I am targeting should look like this:

```
/var/tmpNEW /tmp ext4 loop,rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Please note that ext4 might not always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by using the code:

```
sed -r -i 's/tmp\s(\S+)\s(\S+)/tmp \1 \2,nodev/' /etc/fstab
```

This command remembers the grouping and from there I can append mount options behind the specific matched line.

Comment: That would run foul of some stuff that might exist from older systems, where `/tmp` and `/usr/tmp` might both be mounted file systems.  It depends on how careful you want to be.  (Indeed, you might want the `nodev` option on both `/tmp` and `/usr/tmp` anyway.)  It also adds `nodev` regardless of whether the option is already present.  Again, that may not matter if you've already checked some other way that the `nodev` option is in fact missing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU `sed` (safe enough given that it is RHEL 7), then you could consider:

```
sed -i.bak -r \
    -e '/\s+\/tmp\s+/ { /nodev/! s%\s+/tmp\s+(\S+)\s+% /tmp \1 nodev,%; }' \
    /etc/fstab
```

The first pattern looks for `/tmp` surrounded by spaces; the second pattern looks for lines not containing `nodev` (a little sloppily; it assumes there isn't an alternative option such as `nodeviant` that can appear too).  It then looks for the string consisting of one or more spaces, `/tmp`, one or more spaces, one or more non-spaces, remembered for later use, and one more more spaces again; it replaces that with a space, `/tmp`, a space, what was remembered, another space, and `nodev,`.  This puts the `nodev` option at the start of the options field.  If it must go at the end, do a second lot of remembering and place the option at the end instead.

This handles multiple spaces in the file, and also avoids repeating the `nodev` option and only maps lines containing exactly a space-surrounded `/tmp` (whereas the original answer would mess around with `/usr/tmp` too).